# What does "jerk awake to dwell on something" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, word-meaning, to-infinitive, semantic-roles

> Harry dozed fitfully, sinking into dreams full of clammy, rotted hands and petrified pleading, **jerking awake to dwell again on his mother's voice.**
>
> *Harry potter and the prisoner of Azkaban*

Harry is having a nightmare of his dead mother. So I guess the part marked in bold means something similar, but don't know what *exactly* it means.

It's hard to understand this phrase because I don't know why "to" is used here(grammatical role of "to" maybe?), and also because of "dwell on ~".

Does this mean Harry suddenly woke up, *because of* her mother's voice?

Comment: It's a *slightly* odd juxtaposition of meanings, since ***jerking awake*** is a sudden activity, whereas ***dwelling on** [some obsessive idea]* is a very extended activity. But putting that aside, consider a typical construction like *He jerked awake to find she was gone*. In that (and in your cited example), the "meaning" of ***to*** is simply that the second activity (dwelling on something, or finding something out) came *at the same time or immediately after* the sudden awakening. In your example, there's no sense of "because" whatsoever.

Comment: Another phrase with the same meaning is **awoke with a jerk**.  A jerk is a sudden spasm. *After a night of heavy partying, she awoke with a jerk.*

Comment: It does not mean H.P. awoke 'because' of his mother's voice.  It means H.P. awoke suddenly (contextually due to nightmares) and once awake began to think, obsess, dwell on/about his mother's voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinitival clause there expresses what happens next without any intervening events, and so it can be used to convey a sense of *abruptness* or *surprise*:

> He rounded the corner to find his brother standing there on the sidewalk and speaking on his mobile phone.

He doesn't round the corner with the *intention* of finding his brother. Finding his brother is what happens immediately upon his rounding the corner.

It can also be used to convey a sense of that which is relentlessly true:

> He shook the iron bars to discover again there was no escape from this prison.

In a similar usage, sometimes it is used with the word **only** and then it conveys the sense of a (recurrent) disappointing result:

> He jumped again as high as he could only to fall short of the grapes hanging from the trellis.

Comment: *He rounded the corner to find his brother standing there on the sidewalk and speaking on his mobile phone.* I'm wondering how to paraphrase the sentence. My try: *He rounded the corner and immediately find his brother standing there on the sidewalk and speaking on his mobile phone.*

Comment: @dan:  Try it with **when**.   *When he rounded the corner he found his brother*.... or better yet, with **rounding**:   *Rounding the corner he found his brother....*